# Server app hosted on VPS hangs up

Tags: java, vps

I'm developing a simple server-client app. Server application is hosted on a VPS. I have a problem with it: it behaves weirdly... When I test it on my PC it works fine, but when I launch it on VPS it (program) hangs up when a client app try to connect (the protocol is TCP). I can't even kill it with "killall -vs TERM java" command, so I need to reboot a whole VPS in order to restart it. Client and server apps are both written on Java. The VPS OS is Ubuntu. Can anyone give me a piece of advice of that matter please?

Comment: When you run it locally are both client and server running on the same machine?  Also does the port the server is listening have any networking setting preventing traffic(firewall rules, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was in the System.out.println("some_text") commands. My server didn't want to work without this commands in certain places. Why - I don't know yet. I'll do some researches conducted with that behaviour. But anyway, that's a subject for another question.